# Chromedriver executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.7

Hell, so I am running widows 10 with the latest webdriver in selenium python 3.7. I've had this code work on another machine but when I use it on my new laptop I get the error in the title. I have the driver in my path in multiple places and I specify it in my code, but I have no idea why I am getting this error. My code line below:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Any help on this would be great. I read the other solutions for this and they did not seem to work at all for me

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Taryn, please share the error stack trace you received

Comment: @Navarasu  The error is the title name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of configuring the chrome driver manually.You can use [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/), this will automatically download and set the path of the driver location.

You can get it from pip,

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Now you simply call `ChromeDriverManager().install()` to do it automatically. Instead of worrying about the path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but for some reason I get the exact same error when using this  code and the webdriver manager

Comment: If you are going to post a python snippet, you should also include the import line

Comment: Added import statement to snippet